# How does the rand() operator work?

Tags: sql, t-sql, random

Quickly wanted to ask that does the RAND() operator distribute the values in equal numbers? e.g. If I have 100 rows in a table and a column named NumberOfItems and I want to assign the values 1-10 to them such that it is divided equally between the 100 records (10 records will have 1, 10 will have 2 ......)

The statement I have is:

```
select CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10 as INT)+1
```

Comment: There's no substitute for trying something out. Have you tried building a sufficiently large sample and assessing the distribution therein? I note also that the barebones documentation page on `rand()` mentions that it's pseudorandom only, though not the likely shape of the distribution. As D mentioned, this assumes you're talking in _hypothetical, average_ terms, for a dataset of infinite size - rather than expecting to be given a uniform distribution over a finite set. That wouldn't be random, would it?

Comment: ohk that makes sense. cheers. I just wasnt sure of it thats why I asked.

Comment: I note also that the very barebones official page about `rand()`, although not mentioning any specific distribution, is careful to mention that this function is pseudorandom only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - The *probability* distribution should be uniform, meaning you have the same chance of getting 0.2 as 0.5, but there's no *guarantee* that a specified set of "random" numbers will be uniform.

Comment: No, not in a single operator.  One option would be to "shuffle" the records, assign the values in order (10 1's, 10 2's, etc.) then put them back in the original order.

Comment: I have a couple of other vague ideas. Do you specifically need randomness? If not, and if the rows have a sequential ID number, you could then generate the value from 1~10 using simple arithmetic. If randomness is required, then here is how I would proceed: Build an array of the non-random values you want to distribute. Assign your first value to a (pseudo-)randomly indexed row, selected from those that haven't already had the value filled out (or some other flag set). Repeat until all values have been allocated to rows. D's method is probably easier, but that's just my thought process ;-)

Comment: ya i ll just do it sequentially. I am just testing some technologies so wanted to get some test data on randomly. But sequential is fine, dont wanna spend more than a few mins on it. Cheers guys

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a SQL Server here to test but this will probably work for you.

```
SELECT
        ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.rand_col)) % 10) + 1 as value_col,
        T1.col1,
        T1.col2,
        T1.col3

FROM (
        SELECT col1,
               col2,
               col3,
               RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) as rand_col
        FROM   your_table
      ) T1

ORDER BY T1.rand_col
```

What it does is:

- The subselect T1 is your original table (which I called `your_table`), with an additional random column `rand_col`
- Sort values by this random column in `ORDER BY T1.rand_col`
- Give rows sequential numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ... ) by doing `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.rand_col)`
- Limit that sequential range of numbers to 0-9 by doing `% 10`
- Sum 1 to change the range from 0-9 to 1-10 `(...) + 1

*Some references*

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms186734.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms190279.aspx

Comment: This won't work. `Rand()` returns the same value for all rows.

Comment: It gave me close to what I wanted but I just went with giving the numbers sequentially. Cheers, Guys

Comment: Updated the answer as per Martin Smith comment